# Place json into modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a JSON returned data from a pho function that looks as follows:

```
[{"id":"15","activity_type":"call","activity_title":"Call to check "}]
```

Here the script that initiates the request (actvitiy.js)(Edited)

```
$(document).on("click", ".view_contact_activity", function () {

        var this_activity_id = $(this).closest('.feeds').find('#this_activity_id').val();
        $('#view-contact-activity').modal('show');
    $.ajax({

        url: '../includes/functions/contact-functions.php',
        data: {view_activity_id:this_activity_id},
        dataType:'json',
        Success: function(response){
        $('#activity_id').val(response[0].id);
        $('#activity_type').val(response[0].activity_type);

        }
            });
});
```

The modal where i need the values to show:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="view-contact-activity" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="portlet-body form">
              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="view-contact-activity-form" method="post">

                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-lg-3"> Activity Title</label>
                      <input type="text" name="activity_id" id="activity_id" value="">
                   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label col-lg-3"> Activity Type</label>
                        <input type="text" name="activity_type" id="activity_type" value="">                                                
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                          <button type="submit" name="create-new-account" class="btn btn-danger" id="edit">Edit Activity</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal shows but no data is passed into the modal. Any ideas what i might be doing wrong here.

EDIT: Adding PHP function that returns the JSON

```
function view_activity(){

        global $connection;

        $activity_id = $_POST['view_activity_id'];
        $get = "SELECT * FROM contact_activities WHERE activity_id = '$activity_id' "
                                    or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $get);
        $activitiy_field = array();

        while ($activity_array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

            $activity = array(
                'id' => $activity_array['activity_id'],
                'activity_type' => $activity_array['activity_type'],
                'activity_title'=>$activity_array['activity_title'],
                'activity_details'=>$activity_array['activity_details'],
                'activity_status'=>$activity_array['activity_status'],
                'activity_details'=>$activity_array['activity_details'],
                'activity_details'=>$activity_array['activity_details'],

                );

        $activitiy_field[] = $activity;

        }
                echo json_encode($activitiy_field);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['view_activity_id'])) {
        view_activity();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think it grabs the HTML at the time you call `.modal('show')` and copies it to a separate div, so your HTML changes have no effect since they happen after the modal is already open. Try moving `$('#view-contact-activity').modal('show');` to the bottom of the ajax success callback.

Comment: @MattBrowne I tried it, no changes. i placed after closing the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Use .val() instead of .html().

```
$('#activity_id').val(response.id);
$('#activity_type').val(response.activity_type);
```

Modified: Your javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".view_contact_activity", function () {

    var this_activity_id = $(this).closest('.feeds').find('#this_activity_id').val();

    $('#view-contact-activity').modal('show');

    $.ajax({
        url: '../includes/functions/contact-functions.php',
        data: {view_activity_id:this_activity_id},
        dataType:'json',
        Success: function(response){
            $('#activity_id').val(response[0].id);
            $('#activity_type').val(response[0].activity_type); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it. nothing still. when i type (response.id or response.activity_type) the (id) is highlighted but activity_type is not. not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: What happens when you put a console.log(response); after your .Success?

Comment: in firebug (html) i get the array correctly. [{"id":"12","activity_type":"meeting","activity_title":"meeting","activity_details":"ds","activity_status":""}

Comment: It appears that you are returning an array of objects.  Try $('#activity_id').val(response[0].id);

Comment: Tried it earlier. same result.

Comment: I added the function the returns the JSON.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows it working (modified slightly...) http://jsfiddle.net/scottieslg/d67zujd8/2/

Comment: Good catch about val()  instead of html(), but his HTML is not malformed as far as I can tell. XHTML is not required and is arguably even detrimental unless you're sure to get the MIME type right. See http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, I learned something new today!  I have modified my answer.

Comment: @Scottie thanks for the fiddle, but the fiddle you created also is not working.

Comment: @EDarrien: Sorry, linked the wrong revision.  Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/scottieslg/d67zujd8/3/

Comment: @Scottie not sure why its not working. The modal shows correctly. firebug shows a GET request is sent and the json is returned. could it be the array type?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your original question and paste the current javascript you are using.  What is pasted right now won't work.

Comment: @Scottie see the edit. i believe it matches your recommendation.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is maybe you have another id="activity_id" somewhere in your DOM.  Try doing console.log($("#activity_id").length); and see if you get more than 1.

Comment: @Scottie for some reason i got 0. the modals which contains the "activity_id" field is loaded from another page via "include" statement. The modal loads correctly. but i am not sure why the JSON cannot see the field. Digging in it now..

Comment: @Scottie I now have 1 filed with id "activity_id" but no use. i am starting to pull hair out here :)

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track anyways...  I'm not sure how else to help with the include...

Comment: @Scottie Just wanted to let you know i was able to resolve the issue. will post the resolution in answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After digging on multiple sites. i found a similar question that could help.

```
$(document).on("click", ".view_contact_activity", function () {

        var this_activity_id = $(this).closest('.feeds').find('.id #this_activity_id').val();
    $('#view-contact-activity').modal('show')

    $('#view-contact-activity').on('show.bs.modal', function() { 
        $modal = $(this);
        $.ajax({
           url: '../includes/functions/contact-functions.php',
           data: {view_activity_id:this_activity_id},
           dataType:'json',
           success: function(response){
               // Find the elements in the modal
               $modal.find('#activity_id').val(response[0].id);
               $modal.find('#activity_type').val(response[0].activity_type);
           }
        });
    });
});
```